# String interpolation in logRequest and logResult in akka-http

Tags: akka-http

I am using `akka-http` + the directives `logRequest` + `logResult`

I have something along those lines

```
def entryPoint() = {
    val sid = UUID.randomUUID().toString
    logRequest( s" request[$sid]") {
      logResult(s"response[$sid]") {
          val sid2 = UUID.randomUUID().toString
          println(s"sid2 : $sid2")
          complete("Ok")
      }
    }
}
```

A 1st request prints `sid` and `sid2` :

```
sid  = 87c7db3a-96bc-456d-a747-4a0388eebf65 
sid2 = 0eea70d7-9464-4bef-b62b-fc503de5cc60
```

A 2nd request prints the same `sid`, but a different `sid2`

```
sid  = 87c7db3a-96bc-456d-a747-4a0388eebf65
sid2 = 7355eeb0-f324-44a4-a61a-e629ba1a224f
```

Is the marker of `logRequest` evaluated once and reuse ?
If this is the case, any hint on how to use string interpolation in the marker?

Thanks

Comment: What is `entryPoint()`? When is it ran?

Comment: `entryPoint` is the route definition. It is ran on the server binding `Http().bindAndHandle(endPoints, host, port)`

Comment: `sid` is only calculated once, on binding. Then your `logRequest` and `logResult` are just re-reading this already calculated value for all requests